# Google Sheets and query search

Tags: google-sheets-formula

how to get data of Col1,4 where col5= mainsheet G3:G
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_lqnwF_zbSSVFvRbHcTKJAeqNl3WDF86qwQ-uF-B4d0/edit#gid=1639725347", "FG!A2:M"), "SELECT Col1, Col4 WHERE Col5 '" & G3:G3000& "'")
Error
Query completed with an empty output.
answers, suggestions, tried different ways, but not getting the desired output.

Comment: I can't make sense of this question. It needs reformatting and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(importrange("1_lqnwF_zbSSVFvRbHcTKJAeqNl3WDF86qwQ-uF-B4d0","FG!A2:M"),
      "Select Col1, Col4 where Col5 matches '"& textjoin("|",1,G3:G) &"'")
```